# Return previous row when using boolean indexing

Tags: pandas

**Question**

How do I return the previous row, as well as the row meeting a condition, when using boolean indexing?

**Example**:

```
sodf = pd.Series([9,10,10,9,10,11])
sodf

0     9
1    10
2    10
3     9
4    10
5    11
dtype: int64
```

**Boolean condition:**

```
sodf[sodf == 11]

5    11
```

**Desired output:**

```
4    10
5    11
```

Comment: What should be the output if the condition is `sodf == 10`?

Comment: All rows apart from row 5 would be returned @PabloC

Comment: does the order matter?

Comment: @PabloC Yes order matters.

Comment: What if the condition is `sodf == 9`? should it return the last value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of `sodf==11` and then get the `loc` value -1 onwards.

Here's how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

sodf = pd.Series([9,10,10,9,10,11])

x = sodf[sodf == 11].index[0]
print (sodf.loc[x-1:])
```

Output will be:

```
4    10
5    11
```

If you just want the value of the previous row, then you can also give

```
print (sodf.loc[x-1])
```

The output will be just the value as this is a pd.Series with one column:

```
10
```

Comment: this only works if there is only one occurrence of `11` and it is the last value in the Series

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
i = sodf[(sodf == 9)].index
i = i.union(i-1)
i = i[i>=0]

sodf[i]
```

**Output**

```
0     9
2    10
3     9
dtype: int64
```